# Javascript: Removing invitees using remove button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello guys im trying to create an invitee list that can add people to the list and the list can remove the added invitee as well via a remove button.

```
const input = form.querySelector('input');
const ul = document.getElementById('invitedList');

function createLI(text) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text;
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  label.textContent = 'Confirmed';
  li.appendChild(label);  
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = 'remove';
  button.classList.add('remove');
  li.appendChild(button);
  return li;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const text = input.value;
  input.value = '';
  const li = createLI(text);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  
const remove = document.querySelectorAll(".remove") //the problem lies here
remove.forEach(i => {
  i.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const li = e.target.parentNode;
  const ul = li.parentNode;
  ul.removeChild(li)  
  
   })
  });

})
```

It works as intended (can remove invitees) but the console gives an error everytime i try to remove as follows:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
at HTMLButtonElement.

How can I solve this bug? The error is from the forEach loop where i commented.

This is the codepen: https://codepen.io/ShawnTan15/pen/abJwOvO

Comment: Provide your html code.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I posted the codepen

Comment: I updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code as follows:

```
...
const remove = document.querySelectorAll(".remove") //the problem lies here
if (remove.length != 0) { // add this loop

  remove.forEach(i => {
    i.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const li = e.target.parentNode;
    const ul = li.parentNode;
    if(ul != null) ul.removeChild(li)  // add if statement
  
      })
    });

  })
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it still gives the same error 'removeChild' of null

Comment: @ShawnTan I just edited my answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Updated JS code

```
const form = document.getElementById('registrar');
const input = form.querySelector('input');
const ul = document.getElementById('invitedList');

function createLI(text) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text;
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  label.textContent = 'Confirmed';
  li.appendChild(label);  
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = 'remove';
  button.classList.add('remove');
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const li = e.target.parentNode;
  const ul = li.parentNode;
  ul.removeChild(li)
  
   });
  li.appendChild(button);
  return li;
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const text = input.value;
  input.value = '';
  const li = createLI(text);
  ul.appendChild(li);

})
```